# fscanf doesn't always advance pointer

Tags: c, multithreading, file, while-loop, stdio

Running a multithreaded program that reads through a file by breaking it into several chunks and reading the chunks separately.

Here's my function that each thread is executing:

```
void* readText(void* params) {
    int words_scanned = 0;
    /* Get Arguments from struct */
    struct thread_args *arguments = params;

    /* Get unique id used for setting scan start */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock1);
    int thread_num = arguments->thread_num++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock1);

    /* Open the file */
    FILE *file = fopen(arguments->file_name, "r"); /* Read Only */

    /* Seek to correct spot */
    int partition_size = (int) (arguments->file_size/arguments->num_threads); /* Given 1/nth of file size - the number of bytes to read */
    int current_pos = thread_num * partition_size;
    int end = current_pos + partition_size;
    fseek(file, current_pos, SEEK_SET);

    fpos_t start;
    fgetpos(file, &start);

    char bogus_string[20];
    /* Adjust pointer to beginning of next word */
    if (thread_num != 0) {
        fseek(file, -1, SEEK_CUR); /* Move Pointer back by one character */
        if (!isspace(fgetc(file))) { /* If this character is not a whitespace character */
            fscanf(file, "%s", bogus_string); /* Throw away this word and scan to the next, it will be read by the previous thread */
        }
    }

    fpos_t fp;
    int word_counter = 0;
    /* Read through the whole section assigned */
    while (ftell(file) < end) {
        if(thread_num == 1)
            printf("Current location: %ld\n", ftell(file));

        char buffer[50];
        fscanf(file, "%s", buffer);
        words_scanned++;
        if(thread_num == 1)
            printf("Scanned %s, new loc : %ld\n", buffer, ftell(file));


        /* Add string of 6 or more length to results CRITICAL SECTION */
        if (strlen(buffer) >= 6) {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&lock2);
            int* value = get(wordTable, buffer);
            if (value == NULL) {
                insert(wordTable, buffer, 1);
            } else {
                (*value)++; /* Increment Value */
            }
            fgetpos(file, &fp);
            if (!strcmp(buffer, "don’t")) {
                word_counter++;
                printf("Thread %d: %d: %s at loc: %lld\n",thread_num, word_counter, buffer, fp);
                printf("Start = %lld, End = %d\n", start,  end);
            }
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock2);
        }

    }

    //printf("Thread %d scanned %d words.\n", thread_num, words_scanned);
    fclose(file);
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

My debug statements are only for the second thread of four I'm using to text. Here's an example of the bug I'm getting with my output statements:

```
Current location: 3019
Scanned the, new loc : 3023
Current location: 3023
Scanned the, new loc : 3023
Current location: 3023
Scanned prince, new loc : 3030
Current location: 3030
Scanned prince, new loc : 3030
```

You can see that the space-separated tokens are read in but the pointer isn't advanced. The only thing separating these two debug statements is the fscanf call and an increment to a variable I was using for debugging as well.

Also, the other weird thing is that this only happens sometimes. It doesn't happen every time I run the program.

Any and all help would be appreciated. This is my first multithreaded program and only my second program in C. It's for school.

Cheers

Comment: Check the return values of all your file functions. Perhaps 3030 is the end of the file and your next read failed

Comment: `ftell` is not necessarily the current offset, for a text stream (consider opening the file in binary mode if you want to use this method)

Comment: Check the return value of `fscanf()`. If it fails to read something, the buffer will remain unchanged and it will appear as if the same word was read again without advancing the file pointer. Add `*buffer = '\0';` before `fscanf()` to help diagnose such cases.